# how to assign values to textbox in another method which was dynamically created in c sharp

Tags: c#, winforms

how to assign values to text box in start pause button method which was dynamically created in c sharp

```
 public void btn_addtimer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var panel1 = new Panel() 
            { 
                Size = new Size(500, 180), 
                Location = new Point(10, i), 
                BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle 
            };
        TextBox textseconds = new TextBox();
        textseconds.Name = "txtseconds";
        textseconds.Location = new Point(350, 50);
        textseconds.KeyPress += textseconds_KeyPress;
        panel1.Controls.Add(textseconds);


        Button startpause = new Button();
        startpause.Name = "btnstartpause";
        startpause.Text = "Start";
        startpause.Location = new Point(350, 80);
        startpause.Click += btnstartpause_Click;
        panel1.Controls.Add(startpause);

    }
```

Comment: You are assigning values to several properties of the `Button` already in this code. What do you mean?

Comment: Why dynamically create the panel and button?  You can add the panel and the button and hide the button: startpause.Visible =false; then show it when needed. You can assign whatever values you need at that time.

Comment: @user3132774 Can you post your `btnstartpause ` method ?

Comment: @user3132774  Check the answer you need to assign `id` to your textbox\

Answer (score 3):

Use FindControl with a cast:

```
((TextBox)FindControl("textseconds")).Text = "Some text here";
```

Comment: how to assign the text to textseconds.text in btnstartpause method

Comment: its showing FindControl Does not Exist in the current contest

Comment: @rkawano +1 Took your code BTW ! Only thing missing was assigning `id` ,`FindControl` method Searches the current naming container for a server control with the specified id parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Assign Id to them

```
        textseconds.Id ="txtbxScnds";
```

THEN USE

```
((TextBox)FindControl("textseconds")).Text = "Some text here";
```

`FindControl` method Searches the current naming container for a server control with the specified `id` parameter.

However you need to recreate your dynamic controls with every postback.