# Assign value to dinamically created textbox in another method

Tags: c#, textbox

Please dont give me immediately downvotes, I have same question as asked here, [how to assign values to textbox in another method which was dynamically created in c sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786543/how-to-assign-values-to-textbox-in-another-method-which-was-dynamically-created), but FindControl method doesnt exist in current context.

Here is my code

```
private void btnOkreni_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.Name = "txtBoxOpis";
        txt.Text = izabrana[0].Opis;
        Controls.Add(txt);
}

private void btnSledeca_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Karta k in izabrana)
        {
            if (k == izabrana[0])
            {
                continue;
            }
            txtBoxPojam.Text = k.Pojam;

            //((TextBox)FindControl("txtBoxOpis")).Text = k.Opis;
         }
}
```

Comment: What happens at the commented line of code? What issue or error you are facing? Did you go thru the link shared by @pinkfloydx33?

Answer (score 0):

make `TextBox txt;` as public variable , after that initialize it with `txt = new TextBox` , than you are able to get this everywhere within the main class

Comment: He make them dynamically at runtime, which is obvious from his button click handler.

Comment: yah... i see , but who knows :D , maybe he make public only within that method ... and not like variable in the main class of application

Comment: You can't make a variable public inside a method.

Comment: `public` i mean that it is defined only within the method scope... sorry for missunderstanding

Comment: he should make textbox public in the class and than initialize in the method i think

Comment: No, he should leave it like he has it since he is creating them at runtime, and call Control.Find() like the duplicate link suggests

Comment: why not to make like this ? : 

class

TextBox txt;

method 

txt = new TextBox();

another method :

txt.Text = "Example";

Comment: there is no need for it to be public and I understand your answer, but others might not understand it without example

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 thank you :) I am not sure if the title of original question is good or not, but I wouldnt find it that easy, but maybe its just me. I fixed it now, thanks.

Comment: @EAKTEAM thanks for your effort :)

Comment: @mike_cus , great ! post the solution for others to see , maybe other have same problem and find helped

Comment: there is already solution in original question, which I wasnt able to find at first